# Setting C# structure members through IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

My application uses IronPython for users to run scripts. One such script is used for setting the members of a structure.
My Structure is as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Data
{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

I have declared a class level public object for this structure like:

```
public Data data = new data();
```

I am setting the `data` object as the scope variable for IronPython:

```
scope.SetVariable("data", data);
```

In the python script, I am setting the variables `a` and `b`:

```
data.a = 5
data.b = 10
```

But the variables are not changing in the C# code. I have noticed that if I use a normal integer or any other type, those variables are setting.

Is there some issue with using structures? How can I set the C# structure members from IronPython?

Comment: It is a valuetype, so you would need to return `data` and update it in C#. It seems you really just want a `class` instead of a `struct`.

Comment: @leppie: The structure is used to set similar structure members in unmanaged C++. It would be very tedious to create a class with the same members as the structure, pass it to IronPython and get the values then set the structure members from the class.

Comment: Fair point, the only easy solution I see here, is to re-assign `data` value after you done in IronPython, but this 'workflow' might not be desirable.

Comment: @leppie: Can you explain?

Comment: I have created a class with same members as the structure and passing it to `IronPython`. Then I am filling the structure with the values set through `IronPython`. I am using this as a temporary workaround.

Comment: That is probably better than I suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

Use your exposed scope object to provide helper methods to scripts.
When I can't do it in IronPython that is what I do.
IronPython gives me the flexibility of a full language with ifs, fors, and whiles but sometimes the answers for integrating with the C# world are fuzzy so I just build a helper method.

You can even type the parameters because the marshalling works well across function calls.
void SetResult(int a, int b);

The minor comments are probably right you probably are setting the struct but the struct is not a pass by reference it is a pass by value.

You should understand this concept.
Here is a good SO article about it ....
[What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

You can google the concept more yourself.